# ASP MVC technique for supporting multiple languages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, internationalization

I want to make a web app that support multiple languages(English, German, French ...)
I also want to detect the browser language to use as default and also let the user select the language.

What will be the best approach for doing this?

1. To have a separate view for each language. Keep the language in the user's session and render the correct view.
2. To have the string translation in DB, and translate using a custom mechanism each time I render the view.
3. Does MVC have some native support for this?
4. Other option?

Thanks,

Radu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend you going through the [following guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).

Comment: Hi Darin, is this still "the best" way for for MVC5 and emerging MVC6? Any thing interested been added for Globalization into the framework since MVC2?

Comment: @ppumkin Late answer but you can still apply this. Instead of using `<%=Resource.Global.Title%>` you would now use the Razor syntax, like this: `@Resources.Global.Title`